# How i can use BuildMessage in a custom BuildActivity?

Tags: tfs, build-process, workflow-activity

How Can I add BuildMessage(s) in custom BuildActivity?

```
[BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.Agent)]
public sealed class InvokeDotNetReactor : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> SourcesDirectory { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        ...
        BuildMessage bm = new BuildMessage()
        {
            Importance = BuildMessageImportance.High,
            Message = "Hello From Custom TFS Build Activity"
        };
    }
}
```

}

For WorklowActivity there is a special WorkflowInvoker...

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Logging in a CodeActivity can be done using the CodeActivityContext.

Example:

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    context.TrackBuildMessage("Hello from Custom TFS Build Activity", BuildMessageImportance.High);
}
```

`TrackBuildMessage` is an Extension method which can be found in namespace: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities`

Comment: Hi I am currently trying to show a build message for TFS. But i cannot seem to locate this function, in my `CodeActivityContext context` i only have a funcction called Track which takes `System.Activities.Tracking.CustomTrackingRecord`

Comment: I have found it, didnt do enough google, the function is based down in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies` hope this helps someone else

Comment: This is an extension method. You need to add a `using` statement for the namespace `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities` in order to get access to this function.

Comment: @CharlesLambert This should really be in the answer.